# fast way of deleting dygraph series

Tags: javascript, complexity-theory, dygraphs

following situation: Dygraph expects data in following format

```
var data = [[0,1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

which simplifies:

```
[[x0, y10, y20], [x1, y11, y21], ... , [xn, y1n, y2n]]
```

Now deleting a series - a line in the graph - means deleting every ykn from the data array.

`var firstSeriesDeleted = [[0,2], [1,3]]`

Question is: Is there an optimized way to delete out the series with a complexity less than o(n) ?
I'm using lodash framework and basic JavaScript.

Comment: Just clarify, do you want to store only `xn` entity only in data series ? What means deleting a series , `[xn,y1n,y2n]` means series ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're content to simply hide the series, you can use the [`setVisibility`](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#setVisibility) method.

Redrawing the chart is going to require more time than modifying your data array, so don't worry too much about the time complexity of manipulating your data.